# Crypto++ AES code and undefined symbols on linking

Tags: c++, debian, crypto++

I'm trying to build a cryptopp encryptor (Encryptop.cpp class). Below my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "filters.h"

#if defined(CRYPTOPP_NO_GLOBAL_BYTE)
  using CryptoPP::byte;
#endif

namespace common {

    Encryptor::Encryptor() {}
    Encryptor::~Encryptor() {}

    std::string Encryptor::encrypt(std::string text)
    {
        byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
        memset( key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
        memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );

        std::string ciphertext;

        CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

        CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
        stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( text.c_str() ), text.length() + 1 );
        stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

        return ciphertext;
    }

    std::string Encryptor::decrypt(std::string ciphertext)
    {
        byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
        memset( key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
        memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );

        CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );

        std::string decryptedtext;

        CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) );
        stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ciphertext.c_str() ), ciphertext.size() );
        stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

        return decryptedtext;

    }
}
```

I'm getting the following undefined symbols when linking:

```
/home/myself/dev/common/lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)0, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>::BlockCipherFinal(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEC2EPKhm[_ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8Rijndael3EncEEC5EPKhm]+0x3b): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::g_nullNameValuePairs'
/home/myself/dev/common/lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o): In function `CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<(CryptoPP::CipherDir)1, CryptoPP::Rijndael::Dec>::BlockCipherFinal(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
Encryptor.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEC2EPKhm[_ZN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE1ENS_8Rijndael3DecEEC5EPKhm]+0x3b): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::g_nullNameValuePairs'
/home/myself/dev/common/lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP12CBC_ModeBaseE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12CBC_ModeBaseE]+0x128): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
/home/myself/dev/common/lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP14CipherModeBaseE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP14CipherModeBaseE]+0x100): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
/home/myself/dev/common/lib/libcommon.a(Encryptor.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTVN8CryptoPP15SymmetricCipherE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP15SymmetricCipherE]+0xe8): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
```

Am I missing any other libraries (I'm currently linking to libcryptpp), or any missing include file ?

EDIT: 
Installed version of Cryptopp:

```
$ dpkg-query -l | grep libcrypto
ii  libcrypto++-dev                5.6.1-6+deb8u3                     amd64        General purpose cryptographic library - C++ development
ii  libcrypto++-doc                5.6.1-6+deb8u3                     all          General purpose cryptographic library - documentation
ii  libcrypto++-utils              5.6.1-6+deb8u3                     amd64        General purpose cryptographic library - utilities and data files
ii  libcrypto++9                   5.6.1-6+deb8u3                     amd64        General purpose cryptographic library - shared library
ii  libcrypto++9-dbg               5.6.1-6+deb8u3                     amd64        General purpose cryptographic library - debug symbols
ii  libcryptokit-ocaml             1.9-2                              amd64        cryptographic algorithm library for OCaml - runtime
ii  libcryptokit-ocaml-dev         1.9-2                              amd64        cryptographic algorithm library for OCaml - development
```

Comment: where did you get your cryptocpp library from or did you build it yourself?

Comment: From repository: `sudo apt-get install libcrypto++` on Debian.

Comment: And there are no warnings before the errors?

Comment: No. Just the error itself on linking. Compilation goes fine...

Comment: And you are using the headers from the repository too and they're the same version?

Comment: Well, if `apt-get install libcrypto++` installs only one version, yes, that's the only one I've got. The `apt-get` installation is the only `cryptopp` I have on my machine. No other code around...

Comment: hmm, installing `libcrypto++` wont usually install the headers (at least on ubuntu) and you have to install `libcrypto++-dev`. do you know what version of cryptopp you are using?

Comment: Check my EDIT on the post, where I show the crypto versions...

Comment: strange, what makes me suspicious of mixes of versions is that `g_nullNameValuePairs` was changed from being defined in the library to being in the header files in 6.0.0

Comment: What about ProcessLastBlock? Does that changed also? Do I need to change my code?

Comment: Yes in the current version `ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long)` is pure virtual whereas in 5.6.1 it had an implementation in the cpp file. So my guess would be you are using the 5.6.1 headers but somehow linking to a more recent library, maybe there is one somewhere on your link path or something you've installed has overwritten the version installed by apt.

Comment: Crypto++ 5.6.1 is several years old. You should consider upgrading to 6.0 or 7.0. Also, please show you link command.

Comment: @jww 5.6.1 is the current version distributed by his distribution so its not unreasonable to use it, the "-6" in the version probably also indicates it has back ported security patches from the current version.